# Play sound on Click Event

Tags: vb.net, audio, click

Can I make a program that plays a sound every time I click on it somewhere? I really need this. Like, in some operating systems, it plays a sound everytime you click on a window.

Comment: Consider using events in case you're using Win Forms, but read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples are shown using the `Button_Click` [Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx).

[**Playing System Sounds**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c27he2zs(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click            
        My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound( _
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation)
    End Sub
```

[**Playing Specified Sounds**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y3efyhx(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Mysound.wav", _
        AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub
```